expdp of partitioned table - export by range partition
i'm tryng to execute expdp to export sme partitions of a partitioned table. I use
tables=oenwr.table
query="where EVENT_TIMESTAMP < to_timestamp('2022-04-03 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')"
(EVENT_TIMESTAMP is the column artition )
but export start from the last partition out of my range , anyway exports all partitions
.. exported "owner"."table":"SYS_P99999"  15.01 KB
Maybe it's not possible export selected partitions using a query by the partition column?
I could give a list: tables=owner.table:PART_01,..,..,owner.table:PART_09
but it's not very smart, i don't have the list, i have the EVENT_TIMESTAMP range (es. the last month for a DAYLY partitions.
Someone have an idea?
It's seems like a product limit.
Thanks to all,
Andrea
tryng to export with expdp selected partitions bhy a query on the column partition
